# Issue trying to deploy to a remote container using Maven2, Cargo and Jetty 6

Tags: maven, deployment, jetty, cargo, cargo-maven2-plugin

I am trying to deploy a war module (part of a multi module project) to a remote Jetty 6.0.1 container using Cargo 1.0.5, when I do 
`mvn org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.0.5:deploy` (`mvn cargo:deploy` can't find the plugin for some reason)

I get a `Failed to deploy` error, please see below the full stack trace and the relevant pom file, any help will be much appreciated,

Rafael.

`mvn org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.0.5:deploy`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building RTP Matchbet API
[INFO]    task-segment: [org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.0.5:deploy]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: h_t_t_p://192.168.10.210:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/opensymphony/quartz/1.6.3/quartz-1.6.3.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'opensymphony:quartz:pom:1.6.3' in repository central (http://central)
Downloading: h_t_t_p://192.168.10.210:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/jetty/jetty/6.0.1/jetty-6.0.1.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'jetty:jetty:pom:6.0.1' in repository central (http://central)
[INFO] [cargo:deploy {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to deploy [C:\Users\rcastro\Documents\workspace-sts-2.3.2.RELEASE\rtp-platform\matchbet\api\target\rtp-matchbet-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
Response when calling h_t_t_p://192.168.10.210:8080/cargo-jetty-deployer/deploy?path=/rtp-matchbet-api was:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [C:\Users\rcastro\Documents\workspace-sts-2.3.2.RELEASE\rtp-platform\matchbet\api\target\rtp-matchbet-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.JettyRemoteDeployer.deploy(JettyRemoteDeployer.java:121)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.DeployerDeployMojo.performDeployerActionOnSingleDeployable(DeployerDeployMojo.java:80)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.performDeployerActionOnAllDeployables(AbstractDeployerMojo.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.doExecute(AbstractDeployerMojo.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.execute(AbstractCargoMojo.java:268)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Response when calling http://192.168.10.210:8080/cargo-jetty-deployer/deploy?path=/rtp-matchbet-api was:
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.JettyRemoteDeployer.deploy(JettyRemoteDeployer.java:114)
        ... 23 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Response when calling h_t_t_p://192.168.10.210:8080/cargo-jetty-deployer/deploy?path=/rtp-matchbet-api was:
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.JettyRemoteDeployer.deploy(JettyRemoteDeployer.java:114)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.DeployerDeployMojo.performDeployerActionOnSingleDeployable(DeployerDeployMojo.java:80)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.performDeployerActionOnAllDeployables(AbstractDeployerMojo.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.doExecute(AbstractDeployerMojo.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.execute(AbstractCargoMojo.java:268)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 24 12:22:45 GMT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

POM file

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>rtp</groupId>
    <artifactId>rtp-matchbet-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>rtp</groupId>
        <artifactId>rtp-platform</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>jetty6x</containerId>
                            <type>remote</type>
                            <timeout>120000</timeout>
                        </container>
                        <configuration>
                            <type>runtime</type>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.hostname>192.168.10.210</cargo.hostname>
                                <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <deployer>
                            <type>remote</type>
                            <deployables>
                                <deployable>
                                    <groupId>rtp</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>rtp-matchbet-api</artifactId>
                                    <type>war</type>
                                    <properties>
                                        <context>rtp-matchbet-api</context>
                                    </properties>
                                </deployable>
                            </deployables>
                        </deployer>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-deploy</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>rtp</groupId>
            <artifactId>rtp-matchbet-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>rtp</groupId>
            <artifactId>rtp-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>mx4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>mx4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```